# How stream video from webcam to IIS Media Services

Tags: c#, .net, iis, streaming, windows-media-services

I need stream video from my webcam to ISS Media Services like it does Microsoft Expression Studio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the video stream from Expression Encoder to IIS Media Services as described in [Getting Started with IIS Live Smooth Streaming](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/620/getting-started-with-iis-live-smooth-streaming). The webcam needs to be selected as a Live Source Video Device.

Note that [Live Smooth Streaming is available only in Microsoft Expression Encoder Pro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723875%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

**Edit:**

You can replace Expression Encoder with a custom application built using Expression Encoder SDK. For example, see LiveSmoothStreaming sample from the SDK. For documentation, see [Expression Encoder SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728356.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i was unclear. I need do this thing in code (in C# preferably).

Comment: Hey @DmitryShkuropatsky, while researching information I came through your answer. We've decided to go with IIS Smooth Streaming for a project but Encoder 4 Pro is no longer for sale. Is there any software alternative that you'd be glad to suggest, as there is not enough time to develop anything through the SDK. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Same here. Is there another solution?